# Can't get a lable on the y-achse

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to put labels on the y-Achse on my Dash-Code but it is not working, according to some example code I found online.

My code:

```
    import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go

arrayValues = ['28.687', '29.687', '24.687', '21.687', '25.687', '28.687']

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Title'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Fruit', 'value': 'FRUIT'}
           # {'label': 'Tesla', 'value': 'TSLA'},
           # {'label': 'Apple', 'value': 'AAPL'}
        ],
        value='TEMPERATUR'
    ),
    dcc.Slider(
    min=-5,
    max=10,
    step=0.5,
    value=-3,
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', animate=True),
])


@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):

    return {
        'data': [
                {'y': arrayValues} #Important part
            ]
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(
    )
```

I have tried adding *'name' = 'somename'* or *name = 'somename'*, but it is not working, eventhough it should work.
Example:

```
 {'y': arrayValues, 'name' = 'somename'} #Important part
```

I don't get any error or sth, it just doesn't show any results.

Comment: `{'name' = 'somename'}` should be `{name: 'somename'}`.

Comment: no, still not working. Have you tried it?

Comment: Did you read https://plot.ly/python/axes/? I think it's explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is adding labels to the `y-axis` well you can make the axis containing labels, by setting the below properties.

```
{
    'data': [
            {'y': arrayValues} #Important part
        ],
    'layout': {
        'yaxis':{
            'ticktext': ['label-1', 'label-2', 'label-3', 'label-4', 'label-5'], 
            'tickmode': 'array', 
            'tickvals': arrayValues
        }
    }
}
```

So we have added the `layout` object which contains the property `yaxis` which configures the y-axis. When we set the `tickmode` to `array`, `ticktext` array will accept a list of strings as input. This `ticktext` should have their corresponding numeric values as a list assigned to another array `tickvals`, please go through the below modified code and let me know if this solves your issue.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go

arrayValues = ['28.687', '29.687', '24.687', '21.687', '25.687', '28.687']

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Title'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Fruit', 'value': 'FRUIT'}
           # {'label': 'Tesla', 'value': 'TSLA'},
           # {'label': 'Apple', 'value': 'AAPL'}
        ],
        value='TEMPERATUR'
    ),
    dcc.Slider(
    min=-5,
    max=10,
    step=0.5,
    value=-3,
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', animate=True),
])


@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):

    return {
        'data': [
                {'y': arrayValues} #Important part
            ],
        'layout': {
            'yaxis':{
                'ticktext': ['label-1', 'label-2', 'label-3', 'label-4', 'label-5'], 
                'tickmode': 'array', 
                'tickvals': arrayValues
            }
        }
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

To read more visit [Plotly official documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext)

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have found it myself last night, but I was too tired to update the post.